How to find the approximate value of $g(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty z^n/n^{3/2}$ near $z = 1$?
I am trying to calculate how the chemical potential of a non-interacting Bose gas above the condensation temperature, which boils down to obtaining the leading order expansion of the function $g(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n^{3/2}}$, for $z = 1-\epsilon$, as a function of $\epsilon >0$.
Here is a mathematica plot of the function.

I tried naively expanding the binomial series of $(1-\epsilon)^n$, but all the coefficient of the Taylor series are divergent.
For example, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(1-\epsilon)^n}{n^{3/2}} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(1-n\epsilon+\cdots)}{n^{3/2}} = \zeta(3/2) - \epsilon \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^{1/2}} + \cdots$.
Here $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^{1/2}}$ diverges.
From numerics, $\left(g(1-\epsilon) - g(1)\right) \sim -\sqrt{\epsilon}$ upto leading order
(which implies, the chemical potential decreases quadratically with temperature beyond the condensation temperature).
How to demonstrate this square root dependence using analytic methods?

This is called the polylogarithm function of order $3/2$.

Wikipedia outlines a proof of the identity $\operatorname{Li}s(e^\mu) = \Gamma(1 - s) (-\mu)^{s-1} + \sum{k=0}^\infty {\zeta(s-k) \over k!} \mu^k$, which gives the higher order terms.

Notice that the function could also be inversed for small values of $\epsilon$

Note that your function is the polylogarithm of order $\frac{3}{2}$:
$$ \operatorname{Li}_{3/2}(z) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n^{3/2}} $$
Invoking the gamma integral $\frac{\Gamma(\alpha)}{s^{\alpha}} = \int_{0}^{\infty} t^{\alpha-1} e^{-st} \, \mathrm{d}t$, valid for $\operatorname{Re}(\alpha) > 0$ and $\operatorname{Re}(s) > 0$, it is easy to obtain the following integral representation,
$$ \operatorname{Li}_{3/2}(z) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(\frac{3}{2})} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{z \sqrt{t}}{e^t - z} \, \mathrm{d}t, $$
valid for all $z \in \mathbb{C}\setminus[1,\infty)$.
Now, consider $z = 1 - \varepsilon$ for sufficiently small $\varepsilon > 0$. Then
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Li}_{3/2}(1-\varepsilon) - \operatorname{Li}_{3/2}(1)
&= - \frac{1}{\Gamma(\frac{3}{2})} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\varepsilon \sqrt{t} e^t}{(e^t - 1)(e^t - 1 + \varepsilon)} \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&= - \frac{\sqrt{\varepsilon}}{\Gamma(\frac{3}{2})} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\varepsilon^2 \sqrt{s} e^{\varepsilon s}}{(e^{\varepsilon s} - 1)(e^{\varepsilon s} - 1 + \varepsilon)} \, \mathrm{d}s, \tag{1}
\end{align*}
where the substitution $t = \varepsilon s$ is used in the last step. In order to make use of the last line, we remark that $e^{x} - 1 \geq x e^{x/2}$ holds for all $x \geq 0$. (This is easily proved by invoking Jensen's inequality.) From this, we get
$$ \frac{\varepsilon^2 \sqrt{s} e^{\varepsilon s}}{(e^{\varepsilon s} - 1)(e^{\varepsilon s} - 1 + \varepsilon)} \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{s}(s + e^{-\varepsilon s/2})}, $$
This bound shows that dominated convergence theorem is applicable, yielding
\begin{align*}
\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0^+} \frac{\operatorname{Li}_{3/2}(1-\varepsilon) - \operatorname{Li}_{3/2}(1)}{\sqrt{\varepsilon}}
&= - \frac{1}{\Gamma(\frac{3}{2})} \int_{0}^{\infty} \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0^+} \frac{\varepsilon^2 \sqrt{s} e^{\varepsilon s}}{(e^{\varepsilon s} - 1)(e^{\varepsilon s} - 1 + \varepsilon)} \, \mathrm{d}s \\
&= - \frac{1}{\Gamma(\frac{3}{2})} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{s}(s+1)} \, \mathrm{d}s \\
&= -2\sqrt{\pi}.
\end{align*}
Therefore
$$ \operatorname{Li}_{3/2}(1-\varepsilon) = \operatorname{Li}_{3/2}(1) - 2\sqrt{\pi \varepsilon} + o(\sqrt{\varepsilon}) $$
as $\varepsilon \to 0^+$.

Addendum. Further terms in the asymptotic expansion of $\operatorname{Li}_{3/2}(1-\varepsilon)$ can be found by expanding the integrand of $\text{(1)}$ as a power series in $\varepsilon$,
\begin{align*}
&\frac{\varepsilon^2 \sqrt{s} e^{\varepsilon s}}{(e^{\varepsilon s} - 1)(e^{\varepsilon s} - 1 + \varepsilon)} \\
&\qquad = \frac{1}{\sqrt{s}(s+1)}
+ \frac{\sqrt{s}}{2(s+1)^2} \varepsilon
- \frac{s^{3/2} (s^2+3s-1)}{12 (s+1)^3} \varepsilon^2
+ \cdots,
\end{align*}
and integrating term-by-term, although rigorously justifying this would require much more works.

@Arenius’s nice idea can be worked out in detail here:
The euler maclaurin formula states that
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(n) = \int_{1}^{\infty}  f(n) dn + \frac{f(\infty) - f(1)}{2} + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} B_k\frac{f^{(k)}(\infty) - f(1))}{k!}$$
(Here the bernoulli numbers are indexed by $B_k$ where odd $k$ are 0).
Then we have that:
$$g(1-\epsilon) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(1-e)^n}{n^{3/2}} = -\int_1^{\infty} e^{n \ln(1-e) - 3/2 \ln(n)} dn + \frac{\frac{(1-\epsilon)^{\infty}}{\infty^{\frac{3}{2}}} + \frac{1-\epsilon}{1} }{2}… $$
If we assume that $|1-\epsilon| < 1$ then all of the terms $(1-\epsilon)^{\infty}$ go to 0, and so after the integral all the terms are effectively absorbed into some constant which (I expect but have not proven yet) is directly killed off by the $g(1)$.
Thus
$$ g(1-\epsilon) - g(1) \sim   -\int_1^{\infty} e^{n \ln(1-\epsilon) - 3/2 \ln(n)} dn  $$
Now we go ahead and expand this expression using mathematica:
$$ -\int_1^{\infty} e^{n \ln(1-\epsilon) - 3/2 \ln(n)} dn  = -2\left(\sqrt{\pi} \sqrt{-\ln(1-\epsilon)} \text{erfc}\left(\sqrt{-\ln(1-\epsilon)}\right) + \epsilon - 1 \right) $$
Now we expand this function $ -2\left(\sqrt{\pi} \sqrt{-\ln(1-\epsilon)} \text{erfc}\left(\sqrt{-\ln(1-\epsilon)}\right) + \epsilon - 1 \right)$ as a series using mathematica: to yield that
$$ g(1 - \epsilon) - g(1) = 2 - 2 \sqrt{\pi \epsilon} + ...  $$
And those are all higher order terms which disappear faster than $\sqrt{\epsilon}$ as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$.
This explanation of course brushes "ignoring the other Euler terms" under the rug and should have a proof of this but this covers the main idea you need to see and reproduces @Sangchul's lee more direct result.

$$g(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n^{3/2}}=\text{Li}_{\frac{3}{2}}(z)$$
Let $z=1-\epsilon$ and expand the resulte as a Taylor series around $\epsilon=0$ to get
$$\zeta \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)-2 \sqrt{\pi } \sqrt{\epsilon
   }-\zeta \left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \epsilon -\frac{1}{2}
   \sqrt{\pi } \epsilon ^{3/2}+\frac{1}{2} \left(\zeta
   \left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)-\zeta
   \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\right) \epsilon ^2+O\left(\epsilon
   ^{5/2}\right)$$ which is a quite good approximation (the relative error starts to be larger than $1$% when $\epsilon > 0.25$).

How did you compute that Taylor series?

If you expand as a Taylor series, how would you get the fractional powers?

@ArchismanPanigrahi. OK : make $z=1-\epsilon^2$

Even if you redefine $\epsilon \rightarrow \epsilon^2$, they are still fractional powers.

@ArchismanPanigrahi. Not at all. Have a look at  https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Series%5BPolyLog%5B3%2F2%2C+1+-+x%5E2%5D%2C%7Bx%2C0%2C6%7D%5D

I meant fractional powers in $\epsilon^2$. That is a valid series expansion, but it is not a Taylor series.

One can use Mathematica to check that this is correct, but I don't think it's easy to prove. As far as I can tell, you need to use an integral representation to derive it. You can't simply differentiate the series term by term.
